# Find all increments of +1's starting from a given number in a column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns x and y

```
x            Y

0            1
1.645        7.897
3.444        6.4387 
2.345        5.9090
3.890        5.4322
4.789        3.4321
5.666        4.1111
```

keeping x at a constant value ( say i pick 3.890) i want to find all increments of +1's of the corresponding Y column . In the above example I want (5.4322 + 1 + 1 + 1 ) upto a certain range.In the above example i want the values (6.4387, 7.987) .If an exact +1 value does not exist i want the closest value to it .Is there a formula i can use to achieve this in excel ? . Any help is much appreciated.

expected output :

```
New column

5.4322
6.4387
7.897
```

Comment: The question is not very clear. If you choose 3.890, which one is the expected output and why?

Comment: Hello David , appreciate the response . If I chose 3.890 I will take the equivalent Y value which is 5.4322 and find all it's increment of +1 which in the above case is 6.4387, 7.897 etc (if exact +1 is not present the closest one should do )

Comment: So the expected output is 3? or 8.4322 = (5.4322 + 1 + 1 + 1) ? or 7.897? All the data is sorted?

Comment: Hey David , updated the question with the expected output . The data is not sorted.

Comment: @kauschan you have added critical information forunderstanding your Q as a comment.  Edit it into the Q, or you risk closure as unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have the following **named ranges**:

- **x** being values under `x` column;
- **y** being values under `y` column;
- **Pick_x** being the selected value from `x` column.

[image: Solution]

Enter the following formula in Cell `G2` and drag it down to `G8`:

```
=IF(INDEX(y,MATCH(Pick_x,x,0))+1*(ROW(A1)-1)>MAX(y),"",INDEX(y,MATCH(Pick_x,x,0))+1*(ROW(A1)-1))
```

It will return the `corresponding y value +1s` based on the selected `x` value, but will show blank if the `+1` value is outside the range set by `y` column.

Then enter the following **array formula** (confirm by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in the formula bar) in Cell `H2` and drag it down to `H8`:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(y,MATCH(MIN(ABS(y-G2)),ABS(y-G2),0)),"")}
```

It will return the corresponding closes match from `y` column based on the value in `Column G`, and return blank if there is no value in `Column G`.

I used `Column G` as a helper column but you can choose to replace `G2` in the second formula with the first formula, but it will make the formula too long to be easily understood.

If I change the `x` value to **4.789**, `Column H` will return the following:

[image: Example]

Let me know if I've misinterpreted your question. Cheers :)

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for . Thank you so much